# Format number with percent sign

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spreadsheet

How can I add format for percentage in Spreadsheet.

In Ruby the logical way to do this is something like:

```
number.to_s + "%"
```

However, I want to avoid representing a [number as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49899882/ignore-number-stored-as-text-warning-rails) and I have been trying to use `number_format` with the Spreadsheet gem.

I have tried things like:

```
percent_format     = Spreadsheet::Format.new :number_format => '###000 %'

percent_format     = Spreadsheet::Format.new :number_format => '#0 %'
```

resulting in (respectively):

7500%

7500%

The number that format is on is 75, so it is like the percent sign symbolises "00" also.

I have also asked on the Gems Github Issues section: https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/issues/212

Comment: I did not test , but I feel you should pass 0.75 instead: `(number/100.0)`

Comment: @iGian I think you might have cracked it, I was also trying to divide by 100 but not 100.0. Let me confirm later today and I will get back to you.

Comment: @iGian If you answer I will give you the check mark and the up vote. Thanks.

Comment: happy for being helpful, thanks.

Comment: We use a fork of the `fast_excel` gem but we pass a decimal with the following number format: `0.000%`. You can use our fork here and it will automatically detect strings that are percentages, like "75%" and format it properly as percentages in Excel for you: https://github.com/cntral/fast_excel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn’t test, but I feel you should pass 0.75 instead: `(number/100.0)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rails you can use [proper number helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_percentage)

Or you can try to do it via Ruby formatters:

```
'%.2f%' % 1.23456 => 
"1.23%"
```

If you need just a rounded number without the percent sign:

```
33.22212323.round(2) => 33.22
33.round(2) => 33.0
```

Comment: Hi, I need the percent sign. I also need the number to not be a string but thanks for the help.